# JQGrid Column chooser format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

plugin used - jquery.jqGrid-4.4.4 and
custom theme used - jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css

I need to format the display of the JQGrid column-chooser to look like [THIS EXAMPLE](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithColumnChooser5.htm)

but I dont seem to get even the similar sort of option to choose columns, instead a list box is presented to select the rows from as in below image [image: Select], by pressing "Ctrl" key for the user. Also upon the click of the "OK" Or "Cancel" the jquery.1.9.0.js throws exception as in the image [image: ColumnChooserError.png]

The order of reference of my files and links is as below :-

Sequence of JS reference

```
<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui/jquery.multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-grid/jquery.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/20110223/json2.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Content/jquery-grid/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-grid/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-grid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/Custom_Scripts/list.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The JS for the JQGrid function is stored in the file "list.js", referenced in the end.

And the JS in it is as below :-

```
$("#jqTable").GridUnload();
var mydata = { id: 1, name: 'abc' };
var mygrid = jQuery("#jqTable").jqGrid({
    url: perfectmspURL,
    mtype: 'POST',
    postdata: { 'mydata1': function () { return JSON.stringify(mydata); } },
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: data.colNames,
    colModel: data.colModel,
    multiselect: false,
    pgbuttons: true,
    rowNum: 25,
    //scroll:true,
    //rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
           autowidth:true,
        //    width: 1100,
    height: "98%",
    //scrollOffset: 0,
    //forcefit: true,
    shrinktofit: false,     
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
    //pginput:false, 
    sortname : 'CompanyName',
    sortorder : 'desc',
    pager: jQuery('#jqTablePager'),
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true
});

// appending the pager
jQuery("#jqTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqTablePager', { del: false, add: false, edit:     false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });


// for showing show/hide column
var width = parseInt($('#gridcontainer').width()-5);
var grid = $('#jqTable');
grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#jqTablePager',{ caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
             title: "Choose Columns",
             onClickButton: function () {
                 grid.jqGrid('columnChooser', {
                                        done : function (perm) {
                                               // alert("width " + width + "perm : " + perm);
                                                    if (perm) {
                                                        // "OK" button are clicked
                                                        //this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                                                        // the grid width is probably changed co we can get new width
                                                        // and adjust the width of other elements on the page
                                                        //var gwdth = this.jqGrid("getGridParam","width");
                                                        grid.jqGrid("setGridWidth",width);
                                                    } 
                                                    else {
                                                        // we can do some action in case of "Cancel" button clicked
                                                        this.jqGrid("setGridWidth",width);
                                                    }       
                                            }   // done function ends here 
                                        }); 
                                   }   // onClickButton function ends here.
         });      // navButtonAdd ends here
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be issue with the js file order. Try changing your script file import order

first add jquery and then multiselect

Change

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-grid/jquery.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-grid/jquery.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This type of issue comes when the multiselect.js file is not added or path is not correct or added before jquery.js